# Como puxar os 4 posts mais recentes ou visitados wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Como eu puxo os 4 posts mais recentes ou mais visitados no [wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress)?

Answer (score 2):

**Para buscar os posts mais recentes** você pode usar a função [`wp_get_recent_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts), esta função aceita como primeiro parametro um array e como segundo parametro "como você quer o resultado", mas acredito que a configuração abaixo seja suficiente para você.

```
$args = [
    'numberposts' => 4
];

$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args, ARRAY_A );
```

outros parametros que podem ser usados são:

```
'offset' => 0,
'category' => 0,
'orderby' => 'post_date',
'order' => 'DESC',
'include' => '',
'exclude' => '',
'meta_key' => '',
'meta_value' =>'',
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_status' => 'draft, publish, future, pending, private',
'suppress_filters' => true
```

**Para posts mais populares** creio que seja ideal utilizar algum plugin como o [wordpress popular posts](https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-popular-posts/), mas existem diversos outros que você pode encontrar **procurando no Google** por

> `get popular posts wordpress`